# Fluent Validation with Swagger in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, fluentvalidation

I am currently using `Fluent Validation` instead of `Data Annotations` for my Web api and using swagger for API documentation. Fluent validation rules are not reflected in swagger model as i am unable to configure fluent validation rules with swagger schema filter.

[This Blog](http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/2015/10/add-fluentvalidation-rules-to-swagger.html) has a good explanation for using it with ASP.net MVC. but i am unable to configure it to use it in ASP.net Core.

So far i have tried the following code but i am unable to get validator type.

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.SchemaFilter<AddFluentValidationRules>());

public class AddFluentValidationRules : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        model.Required = new List<string>();
        var validator = GetValidator(type); // How?
        var validatorDescriptor = validator.CreateDescriptor();

        foreach (var key in model.Properties.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var propertyValidator in validatorDescriptor.GetValidatorsForMember(key))
            {
                 // Add to model properties as in blog
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After searching i have finally figured out that i needed to `IValidationFactory` for validator instance.

```cs
public class AddFluentValidationRules : ISchemaFilter
{
    private readonly IValidatorFactory _factory;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Default constructor with DI
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factory"></param>
    public AddFluentValidationRules(IValidatorFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void Apply(Schema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {

        // use IoC or FluentValidatorFactory to get AbstractValidator<T> instance
        var validator = _factory.GetValidator(context.SystemType);
        if (validator == null) return;
        if (model.Required == null)
            model.Required = new List<string>();

        var validatorDescriptor = validator.CreateDescriptor();
        foreach (var key in model.Properties.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var propertyValidator in validatorDescriptor
                .GetValidatorsForMember(ToPascalCase(key)))
            {
                if (propertyValidator is NotNullValidator 
                  || propertyValidator is NotEmptyValidator)
                    model.Required.Add(key);

                if (propertyValidator is LengthValidator lengthValidator)
                {
                    if (lengthValidator.Max > 0)
                        model.Properties[key].MaxLength = lengthValidator.Max;

                    model.Properties[key].MinLength = lengthValidator.Min;
                }

                if (propertyValidator is RegularExpressionValidator expressionValidator)
                    model.Properties[key].Pattern = expressionValidator.Expression;

                // Add more validation properties here;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     To convert case as swagger may be using lower camel case
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string ToPascalCase(string inputString)
    {
        // If there are 0 or 1 characters, just return the string.
        if (inputString == null) return null;
        if (inputString.Length < 2) return inputString.ToUpper();
        return inputString.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + inputString.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

and add this class to swaggerGen options

```cs
options.SchemaFilter<AddFluentValidationRules>();
```

Comment: I attempted to follow this solution; however, I'm running into an "InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'FluentValidation.IValidator`1[MyClass]' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'MyConfig'." exception when the factory attempts to get the validator.  My validators sometimes depend on scoped services (such as config).  The default ASP.NET Core DI and validator works correctly when calling the API method directly, but for some reason it fails here.  Did you ever run into this?

Comment: @wdspider Is swagger working for you without fluent validation?

Comment: Yes.  If I remove the `options.SchemaFilter<AddFluentValidationRules>();` line from the swaggerGen options (i.e. not attempt to integrate the fluent validation rules); I successfully get a generated swagger.json file along with the working Swashbuckle UI.  The downside is that it doesn't show any of the validation information which is why I sought out this solution in the first place.

Comment: Have you added fluent validation service? ie `services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(...)`

Comment: @wdspider, seems like your code is Ok. I have also used some other Filters and they also work fine. try using a filter described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074037/1735196

Answer (score 28):

I've created github project and nuget package based on Mujahid Daud Khan answer. I made redesign to support extensibility and supported other validators.

github: https://github.com/micro-elements/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation

nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation

Note: For WebApi see: https://github.com/micro-elements/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation.WebApi

### Supported validators

- INotNullValidator (NotNull)
- INotEmptyValidator (NotEmpty)
- ILengthValidator (Length, MinimumLength, MaximumLength, ExactLength)
- IRegularExpressionValidator (Email, Matches)
- IComparisonValidator (GreaterThan, GreaterThanOrEqual, LessThan, LessThanOrEqual)
- IBetweenValidator (InclusiveBetween, ExclusiveBetween)

### Usage

#### 1. Reference packages in your web project:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.5.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation" Version="0.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="2.3.0" />
```

#### 2. Change Startup.cs

```cs
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        // Adds fluent validators to Asp.net
        .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CustomerValidator>());

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        // Adds fluent validation rules to swagger
        c.AddFluentValidationRules();
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app
        .UseMvc()
        // Adds swagger
        .UseSwagger();

    // Adds swagger UI
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });
}
```

#### Swagger Sample model and validator

```cs
public class Sample
{
    public string PropertyWithNoRules { get; set; }

    public string NotNull { get; set; }
    public string NotEmpty { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string RegexField { get; set; }

    public int ValueInRange { get; set; }
    public int ValueInRangeExclusive { get; set; }
}

public class SampleValidator : AbstractValidator<Sample>
{
    public SampleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(sample => sample.NotNull).NotNull();
        RuleFor(sample => sample.NotEmpty).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(sample => sample.EmailAddress).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(sample => sample.RegexField).Matches(@"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})");

        RuleFor(sample => sample.ValueInRange).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(5).LessThanOrEqualTo(10);
        RuleFor(sample => sample.ValueInRangeExclusive).GreaterThan(5).LessThan(10);
    }
}
```

Feel free to add issues!

Comment: Maybe you should appropriately credit Mujahid within your repository and on the NuGet website?

Comment: Remember that links are volatile, try to add your code in the answer so if some day the link breaks your contribution remains useful.

Comment: I couldnot find any contacts of Mujahid (only stackowerflow user).
I will add link to his answer to readme

Comment: Can you please upgrade swagger version. Currently, version 4 is out but your package is supporting 3.0.0. so i cant use it.

Comment: There is beta version that support v4 but v4 brokes DI issues with scoped services injected in validators.

Comment: what about custom validators?

Comment: OpenApi supports restricted set of validation. Add issue at github and we will see how to help you.

Comment: @Alexey.Petriashev Does this support property validation with predefined list of constant values ? Swagger UI doesn't show the list of allowed values.

Comment: @Hary it works for enums from the box. You can create github issue with your case

Answer (score 10):

1. Install Nuget package: `MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation`
2. Add to ConfigureServices:
   `services.AddFluentValidationRulesToSwagger();`